# How can I combine the output of two separate fields in template.php?

Tags: theming, taxonomy-terms

I have two fields displaying multiple values from select lists. The first field's a term reference field, the second's a text list. So,

**print render($content['field_term_list'])** produces

- Term1
- Term2

and **print render($content['field_text_list'])** produces

- Text-item1
- Text-item2

I'd like to merge the output into a single list, preferably sorted alphabetically, and print it from a new variable:

```
<?php print ($combined_lists); ?>
```

- Term1
- Text-item1
- Term2
- Text-item2

How can this be done using theme_preprocess_node?

Comment: What you will want to do is look at what is actually in `$content['field_XXXX_list']`.  They are "render arrays" and contain all the information in more or less raw form that `render()` then creates the HTML out of.  Craft/sort/do whatever you want with them both in your `preprocess_node()` hook and assign that to a variable and you'll be all set.

Comment: @Peter Clemence, when you say "combined", you'd want to show them in a new dropdown or say, an item list?